# Teclado numérico mobile angular

Tags: angular, mobile, typescript

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um formulário em angular que será utilizado tanto em desktop quanto em mobile.

Porém, gostaria que no mobile os campos numéricos como CPF, Telefone, Cep, apresentasse apenas o teclado numérico e não o teclado completo!

Como posso fazer isso? Lembrando que não posso colocar o type: number no input, pois uso mascaras nesses campos, e o input de type number não ia deixar eu utilizar essas mascaras..

Agradeço desde já...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só modificar o atributo type no input.

```
<input type="number"/>
```

ou

```
<input type="tel"/>
```

**EDIT:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input id="CPF" type="tel" />

    <script>
      var cpf = $("#CPF");
      cpf.mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

[image: ...]

Comment: Na minha pergunta eu informo que não posso fazer dessa maneira, pois utilizo um component de mascara

Comment: O `type="tel"` funciona meu amigo. Vou editar a resposta com um exemplo.